# integration of multiple functions

Tags: calculus, integration

The function is $I = \int x^{-p+1}  \sin x\, dx$ which I have to integrate.
My effort is if I select $x^{-p+1}$  (as first function) and $\sin x$ (as second function) and integrating by parts
$$I = -x^{-p+1} \cos x + (1-p)\int x^{-p}  \cos x\, dx
= -x^{-p+1} \cos x + (1-p) [x^{-p}\sin x + p\int x^{-p-1}  \sin x\, dx]$$

In this way only steps are increasing and no closing steps. Please help me

Comment: Your post is difficult to read.  If you're motivated, a guide to using MathJax on this site (to express mathematical formulas using LaTeX syntax) is [here on Meta.Math.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I think you should integrate by parts in the other direction, if $p$ is positive.  That way your exponent eventually rises to zero, and no further integration by parts is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know something extra about $p$? In some cases it it's possible to express this integral by elementary function, for example for $p=2$ [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20sin%28x%29%2ax%5E%28-1%29)